# Strikethrough equations in cases environment

Tags: cases

I'm trying to put a stroke across an equation inside the cases mode. I tried both ulem and soul packages but I don't understand how they work in the cases environment.

This is what I got with ulem:

[image]

while if I use $ in \sout I got an error.

And here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{cases}
\sout{f(x) \geq 0} \\
g(x) \geq 0 \\
\end{cases}\]

% \[\begin{cases}
% \sout{$f(x) \geq 0$} \\
% g(x) \geq 0 \\
% \end{cases}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `\sout` is a text-mode command provided by the `ulem` package. To "cancel" terms inside math mode, load the `cancel` package and write, say, `\cancel{f(x) \geq 0}`.

Comment: `\[\begin{cases}
\cancel{f(x) \geq 0} \\
g(x) \geq 0 \\
\end{cases}\]` with the `cancel` package??

Comment: Thank you Mico for the welcome and for the fast help! It works!